# Angle of refraction of water in relation to temperature

Tags: waves, visible-light, water

I am an IB diploma student working with the angle of refraction of water.
My goal is to note the change in the angle of refraction with temperature. However, I havent found any noticable change in my experiment. I have shined a 532 nm laser through water stored in a pot, of which I have varied the temperature from 30 to 60 degrees Celsius. As stated before there is no noticable change. This seems very odd to me and any further help would appreciated.

Comment: https://medium.com/@jhood984/how-does-temperature-affect-refraction-of-water-ee-rough-draft-2bae3345d5e The following might be helpful.

Comment: https://www.utsc.utoronto.ca/webapps/chemistryonline/production/refractive.php

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Are you shining the laser straight through your pot, or do you pass at an angle? If you go straight through you wouldn't expect any deflection... if you can provide a sketch of your setup we might be able to help further... oh, Young's links probably give you the answer you need already :)

Comment: More detail is required of your apparatus, method and results. Otherwise we can only make guesses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a table [here](http://optics.sgu.ru/_media/optics/staff/bashkatov/bashkatov_spie_03_5068_393.pdf) that shows a 2% change in refarctive index from 0$^\circ$C to to 100$^\circ$C at 600 nm. Is your setup sufficent to detect a 2% change in $n$?